# Laravel required_with throwing error even when its supposed to be ignored

Tags: laravel

Basic user profile update page with an *optional* password change. Only if theyre trying to change their password, does it request the current password.

Controller:

```
    $this->validate($request, [
        'name'      => 'required',
        'email'     => 'required|email',
        'new_password'  => 'confirmed',
        'current_password'  => 'required_with:new_password|current_password'
    ]);

    $user->name     = $request->get('name');
    $user->surname  = $request->get('surname');
    $user->email    = $request->get('email');
    if($request->get('password') !== ''){
        $user->password = Hash::make($request->get('new_password'));
    }
    $user->save();
```

But validation keeps tripping up and giving me the error "validation.current_password"

View (scaled back for readability):

```
        @if($errors)
            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                <div>{{ $error }}</div>
            @endforeach
        @endif

{!! Form::model($user, ['method'=>'PATCH', 'action'=>['UserController@update', $user->id], 'class'=>'kt-form kt-form--state', 'id'=>'form-user-profile', 'files' => true]) !!}
{!! Form::text('name', null, ['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
{!! Form::password('current_password', ['class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>__('Current Password')]) !!}
{!! Form::password('new_password', ['class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>__('New Password')]) !!}
{!! Form::password('new_password_confirmation', ['class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>__('Verify New Password')]) !!}

{{ Form::button(__('Submit'), ['type' => 'submit', 'class' => 'btn btn-success']) }}
{{ Form::button(__('Reset'), ['type' => 'reset', 'class' => 'btn btn-secondary']) }}

{!! Form::close() !!}
```

As per https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-required-with
required_with only needs to be present if new_password is present. So why am I getting a "validation.current_password" error when I only update my "name" field (for example).

Comment: I've also tried ```required_with_all:new_password,new_password_confirmation``` - same result

Comment: use `sometimes` rules. [sometimes docs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#validating-when-present)

Comment: Adding sometimes to new_password and/or current_password yields same results. Tried renaming current_password (field) to existing_password to see if it was a naming conflict, same results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error you're getting, it is somehow clear that the `required_with` is not the rule behind the error, it actually is the `current_password` rule.

According to the docs, the `current_password` rule does the following check

> The field under validation must match the authenticated user's password

So with that being said, it seems you're not typing the correct password of the currently logged in user which trigger the validation error of the `current_password` rule.

A quick fix could be:

- starting by adding the `nullable` validation rule on both `new_password` and `current_password` fields so the validation can pass when the fields are empty.
- use `required_unless` rule instead of `required_with` which allows you to verify whether `new_password` field is empty (`null`) or not.

> `required_unless`: The field under validation must be present and not empty unless the anotherfield field is equal to any value. This also means anotherfield must be present in the request data unless value is null. If value is null (required_unless:name,null), the field under validation will be required unless the comparison field is null or the comparison field is missing from the request data.

Here's a code sample illustrating what's being said:

```
$this->validate($request, [
  'name' => 'required',
  'email'     => ['required', 'email'],
  'new_password'  => ['nullable', 'confirmed'],
  'current_password'  => ['nullable', 'required_unless:new_password,null', 'current_password']
]);
```

> In the above code sample i used arrays instead of strings to specify the rules. This doesn't have anything to do with the solution, it is used to make the changes clearer and the code more readable

**Bonus Tip:** you're getting `validation.current_password` as the error message is due to the lang files that contain the validation message being deleted. The`EN` version of those files should be under `resources/lang/en/validation.php`. You may simply download that file from GitHub and place it there or you may use your own custom error messages.

> Learn more about [`Validation Rules`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation) on `Laravel` docs.

Comment: Thanks, I had already figured it out - just hadnt updated this thread yet. Simply adding nullable to current_password (everything else staying the same) did the trick - though your logic above is more sound.

Comment: Happy for you! Glad I managed to help even though a little.